# Insert data into foreign key column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following tables:[image]

I want to insert data into user_category.Is there any way to insert data into user_category.user_id reference account.id and user_category.cat_id  reference categories.cat_id.

I am doing this method but can't work:

```
 public function storeID($cat_id,$user_id){

    $stmt = $this->conn->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");
    $stmt= $this->conn->query("INSERT INTO `user_category` (`user_id`, `cat_id`) VALUES (`$user_id`, `$cat_id`)");
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

  }
```

Is there any solution, please refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepare()` function just only prepares query and does not execute it. In your case you can use `query()` instead of `prepare()`

Comment: This also not working.The query is not execute, it showing error Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Comment: You do not have there execute command... Maybe show all code.

Comment: When you use `query` you can not use `execute`. Just remove this line with `execute`

Comment: If it still will not work, just display error: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: It is not working and error is Errormessage: Unknown column  in 'field list'

Comment: Ah... as values you must put id so it must be just: ` VALUES ($user_id, $cat_id)`